# ¿Como puedo cambiar el nombre de una columna en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

He usado:

```
ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla RENAME COLUMN nombre_columna_vieja to nombre_columna_nueva;
```

y no funciona, he visto en varios foros pero sigo sin obtener ayuda...

Comment: No cambia el nombre de la columna? Qué mensaje sale cuando ejecutas ese comando? Algún error? "No funciona" es muy vago para que otros puedan ayudarte de forma efectiva. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento del sitio y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 3):

En MySQL, esa operación se hace así:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE `oldcolname` `newcolname` datatype(length);
```

RENAME COLUMN no aparece en ninguna parte de la documentación de MySQL.

En SO en inglés [también hicieron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql) esta misma pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

El rename solo te sirve para renombrar la tabla, no para la columna, para la columna tienes que usar

```
ALTER TABLE nombretabla 
CHANGE nombrecolumnaactual nuevonombrecolumna tipodedato
```

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así:

```
ALTER TABLE NOMBRE_TABLA
CHANGE NOMBRE_COLUMNA NOMBRE_NUEVO TIPO DATO;
```

Ejemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE PARTIDOS CHANGE COLUMN NOMBRE_ARBITRO COLEGIADO 
VARCHAR(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. En el administrador de bases de datos que maneje hacer la prueba para sacar el query, en el caso de Workbench sería así:

se hace click en `Alter Table...`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se cambia el nombre del campo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se da en apply
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente aqu{i se copia el query
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. La otra opción es usar el siguiente query que extraje usando el método anterior

---

```
ALTER TABLE `<nombre_BaseDatos>`.`<nombre_tabla>`
    CHANGE COLUMN `nombre_campo_actual` `nombre_nuevo_campo` <TIPO_DATO> NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

lo inmediatamente anterior sería así

```
ALTER TABLE `platziblog`.`people`
CHANGE COLUMN `year` `yearsd` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

Comment: Hola MaodeColombia, bienvenido, la pregunta/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos, ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!

Answer (score -1):

Me parece que tienes que poner `TO` en mayúscula. Me suena que los comandos de SQL tienen que ir en mayúscula para que la maquina entienda que se trata de un comando. Al poner `to` en minúscula, me imagino que no lo interpreta como parte del comando.

```
ALTER TABLE ... RENAME COLUMN ... TO ...;
```